# The stabilizer of a cyclic group over a group algebra

Tags: summation, group-actions, cyclic-groups, stabilizer

> Working with the cyclic group of order n, $C_n = \{ e,g,g^2,...,g^{n-1} \} $ and the group algebra of $\mathbb{C}[C_n]$ with multiplication $g^k \cdot z=\eta ^k z$ for $\eta = e^{2\pi i/n}$.

We are given that $$\hat{a}(m)= \Sigma^{n-1}_{k=0} a_k \eta^{-mk}$$ for $m=0,...,n-1$
$$a'_l = \frac{1}{n} \Sigma^{n-1}_{m=0} \hat{a}(m) \eta^{ml}$$ for $l=0,...,n-1$
We want this equation in the form $$\Sigma^{n-1}_{k=0} a_k c_{k,l}$$ for some $c_{k,l}, k,l=0,...n-1$
So far I have got this equation to be $$a'_l= \frac{1}{n} \Sigma^{n-1}_{k=0} a_k \Sigma^{n-1}_{m=0} \eta^{m(l-k)}$$

I'm not too sure how to get this summation to some $c_{k,l}$ but from this I need to look at the values of k & l for which the stabilizer is trivial/non-trivial, I am not too sure what this means?

Comment: I don't understand why you are talking about "the group algebra *of* $\mathbb{C}[C_n]$" (don't you rather mean "the group algebra $\mathbb{C}[C_n]$"?), nor what is this "multiplication $g^k \cdot z=\eta ^k z$" (this is *not* the multiplication of this algebra), and what "stabilizer" (of which element and relatively to which action of which group on which set?) your refer to, in the title and in the final sentence.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $c_{k,l}=$[$\delta_{k,l}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta), i.e. $a'_l=a_l.$ This is the [inversion formula for discrete Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Inverse_transform). You can easily (re-)prove it, using that for any integer $r>1,$ the sum of the $r$ complex $r$-th roots of unity is $0.$